# Find Laplace transform of $f(t)=t^5$

Tags: laplace-transform

I was double checking some Laplace transforms against Wolfram alpha, and I found this result odd.

Let $f(t)=t^{5}$

Using Laplace integration formula $\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt$ we get:

\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty t^5e^{-st}dt=\int_0^\infty te^{5-st}dt
\end{equation}

Here we use integration by parts, with $u=t$, $u'=1$, $v'=e^{5-st}$, and $v=\frac{e^{5-st}}{5-s}$, obtaining:

\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty te^{5-st}dt=\bigg[e^{5-st}\bigg(\frac{t}{5-s}-\frac{1}{(5-s)^2}\bigg)\bigg]_0^\infty=0-1\bigg(0-0\bigg)=0
\end{equation}

But Wolframalpha gives [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laplace%20transform&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22LaplaceTransformCalculator%22%2C%20%22transformfunction%22%7D%20-%3E%22t%5E5%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22LaplaceTransformCalculator%22%2C%20%22variable1%22%7D%20-%3E%22t%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C%20%22laplace%20transform%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22LaplaceTransformCalculator%22%2C%20%22variable2%22%7D%20-%3E%22s%22), which is very different.

What is wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Why did you move the five from $t^5$ to the exponential term?

Comment: Hi  Moo, I forgot that the base has to be equal in order to merge the exponents. Crappy work indeed! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $\tau =st$ so $\frac{d\tau}{dt} = s$ and
$$
\int_0^\infty t^5 e^{-st} dt = \int_0^\infty \frac{\tau^5}{s^6} e^{-\tau} d\tau = \frac{1}{s^6}\Gamma(6) = \frac{5!}{s^6} = \frac{120}{s^6}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to note that
$\mathcal{L} \{t f(t)\} = -f'(s), s>0$
or more generally
$\mathcal{L} \{t^n f(t)\} = (-1)^n f^{(n)}(s), s>0$

Doing this with $f(t)=1, f(s)=s^{-1}$
yields the usual Laplace transforms
$$\mathcal{L} \{t \} = - \frac{d}{ds} s^{-1} =  (1!) s^{-2}$$
$$\mathcal{L} \{t^2 \} = - \frac{d}{ds} s^{-2} =  (2!) s^{-3}$$
$$\mathcal{L} \{t^3 \} = -(2!) \frac{d}{ds} s^{-3} =  (3!) s^{-4}$$
from which you deduce/prove
$$\mathcal{L} \{t^5 \} = (4!) \frac{d}{ds} s^{-5} =  (5!) s^{-6}$$
or more generally
$$\mathcal{L} \{t^n \} =  (n!) s^{-(n+1)}$$